# VT choice: past continuous vs. past perfect continuous

Tags: grammar

I am trying to describe a working state in a period of time.

> A few years ago, I was running my own business. At that time, I was working 15 hours a day for around 10 months.
>
> ... I had been working 18 hour long days over a period of around 10 month.
>
> ... I had worked 18 hours a day for about 10 months.

Are those all grammatically correct? Which one is better?

Answer (score 0):

The first one isn't quite right. "18 hour long days" doesn't sound right. The idiomatic thing to say is "18 hour days".

So this sentence should be: "I had been working 18 hour days over a period of around 10 months"

The last one is fine. (For some reason, it sounds slightly odd to me, because "18 hours a day" is extreme, yet "about 10 months" sounds so...casual. I think in practice people would say something like "I had worked 18 hours a day for 10 months straight" or "over 10 months" or something more emphatic.)

Comment: At that time I was working about 15 hours a day and it lasted about 10 months without using pas perfect. Does this solution work or not

Comment: Yes. I'd say "*that* lasted about 10 months" though.

Answer (score 0):

A few years ago, I was running my own business. At that time, I was working for 15 hours a day for about 10 months.
(This is what you may hear someone say.)

I had been working for 18 hours a day over a period of around 10 months
(Grammatically correct and sounds better)

I had worked 18 hours a day for about 10 months.
(Grammatically correct but the use of "been" is better)

Answer (score 0):

"I had been working" is past perfect continuous, and "I had worked" is past perfect.

Both sentences are used to place the activity or event being described **before** some other event. Your sentence does not contain any other event, so both sentences sound equally incomplete. To make them sound right, you would need to add a clause or phrase that defines some other event.

For an activity that took place over a long period of time, past perfect continuous is the right choice. Here are two examples that define the other event:

> I had been working 18 hour days over for around 10 months **before** I was able to take a holiday.

> I had been working 18 hour days over for around 10 months **when** I first met Ahmed.